# Why all stochastic integrals are taken with respect to Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I feel like we could integrate with respect to any process with continuous paths. Can we expand Ito calculus to other processes?

Comment: It is not true that only integrals w.r.t. Brownian motion have been studied. One can define stochastic integrals w.r.t. what are called random measures and this definition is much more general  than integrals w.r.t. to 'nice' independent increment processes.

Comment: Ito calculus already do integrals with respect to semimartingales that are not necessarily related to Brownian motions.